# Set default program for one specific file in Nemo

Tags: files, pdf, file-opening, nemo

There's a lot of questions on how to change the default program for a specific file extension, but I want to know if I can change the default program for a specific *file*.

Reason: Some PDFs don't open well on Okular -- they crash the program and can't be opened at all basically. So I have to right click and open with Adobe Reader... every single time. Most of my files open well with Okular, but for the one or two that don't, I want to make them open in Adobe Reader by default instead. I already mark them with emblems so I know which ones they are, but still to right click those particular problematic PDFs and select "Open With..." each time is annoying.

So, is there a way that I can set the default program for *one specific file* but leave the other PDFs opening with Okular?

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon if that makes a difference.